# What are the technical certification requirements for the Xbox 360?

Tags: xbox360, microsoft

I came across [this document](http://blog.csdn.net/baozi3026/archive/2009/06/16/4272761.aspx) listing the technical certification requirements from March 2009, but I haven't been able to track down anything more up-to-date, nor have I been able to find the "terminology list" that the document refers to.

Is there a current version that is available to non-developers like myself?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The official up-to-date TCR document comes with the Xbox Development Kit from Microsoft. Any licensed developer copying it online would be in violation of the license terms of the XDK.

It is possible that Microsoft has published it elsewhere, or that they have given some other developers or journalists a separate license to publish it. But I think that's unlikely. Most of the requirements, as you can see in the linked document (which was probably posted infringingly), are fairly boring.

Comment: Thanks. I had a feeling this was the answer, but I thought it couldn't hurt to ask.